# In pandas how to parse a column which has many attribute and values into new columns and get their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame which consists many columns and one of them column called SourceTechAttributes which has valuable attributeName and attribute Value such as

```
    df['SourceTechAttributes'][0]
    'DropFrame: True, Duration: 4874.1359333333333333333333333, FieldDominance: Upper Field First, FrameRate: 29.97, Height: 1080, MediaFormat: 912, NumberOfAudioChannels: 8, NumberOfAudioTracks: 8, ScanType: Interlaced, StartSmpte: 00:59:59;26, ViewportDisplayFormat: Anamorphic, Width: 1920'
0    DropFrame: True, Duration: 4874.13593333333333...
1    ActionType: CG, DropFrame: True, Duration: 129...
2    DropFrame: True, Duration: 4874.13593333333333...
3    DropFrame: True, Duration: 4874.13593333333333...
4    ActionType: CG, DropFrame: True, Duration: 129...
5    ActionType: CG, DropFrame: True, Duration: 129...
Name: SourceTechAttributes, dtype: object
```

This column key and value also changes its position, 
I want to parse that column and create new seven column such as below
[image]

I can do in pandas one by one such as

```
df['m']=df['SourceTechAttributes'][0].split(',')[0]
```

which gives me a results of parse of first comma separated such as

```
df['m']
0        DropFrame: True
1        DropFrame: True
2        DropFrame: True
3        DropFrame: True
```

then again parse colon separated and take the last part and give the column name as df['DropFrame']

```
df['DropFrame']=df['m'][0].split(':')[1]
df['DropFrame']

0         True
1         True
2         True
3         True
```

But this process gives wrong because sometime it does not get what i want to as because of some rows the attributes and values are many and sometime few. Can Anyone please help me on that matter to create a function that will take care all of this and I can achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do not post code or data as images - no one can copy it for testing purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a function that takes a string, splits it by commas and then by colons, and converts to a pandas Series through a dictionary:

```
def str2series(s):
    pieces = [x.split(': ') for x in s.split(',')]
    return pd.Series({k.strip(): v.strip() for k,v in pieces})
```

Next, apply the function to the column:

```
new_df = df.SourceTechAttributes.apply(str2series)
```

The result is a dataframe that you are looking for. You can merge it with the original dataframe, if you want: they have the same index:

```
df = df.join(new_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Dyz when i apply that str2series function on new_df, i get error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You should not apply it to new_df. You should apply it to the string column of the original dataframe.

Comment: I mean to my existing df to create a new_df, such as new_df = df.SourceTechAttributes.apply(str2series),  and when i run that getting error <ipython-input-117-c39868653faa> in str2series(s)
      1 def str2series(s):
----> 2     pieces = [x.split(': ') for x in s.split(',')]
      3     return pd.Series({k.strip(): v.strip() for k,v in pieces})

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: And if i change that column types as str such as df['SourceTechAttributes'] = df['SourceTechAttributes'].astype(str) ; then when i execute new_df = df.SourceTechAttributes.apply(str2series) ; it give me error saying <ipython-input-136-c39868653faa> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 def str2series(s):
      2     pieces = [x.split(': ') for x in s.split(',')]
----> 3     return pd.Series({k.strip(): v.strip() for k,v in pieces})

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Apparently some strings in that column have a different format from what you show in the example. Please check and update your question

Comment: you are right, as that column has been constraucted from sql stuff method and consists of various type of data type, So how can i accomplish this job, any idea? Thanks

Comment: At the very least you must update the question and include all relevant data patterns.

Comment: I have update my questions and give couple of more data. If you can please help me.

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 1):

Below 3 steps:

```
# 1. create a list in each row
df['SourceTechAttributes'] = (df['SourceTechAttributes']
                              .apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(" ", "")
                                     .replace(":", ",")
                                     .split(",")))

# 2. create a dictionary in each row
df['SourceTechAttributes'] = (df['SourceTechAttributes']
                              .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))))

# 3. create new columns
df['srcMediaFormat'] = (df['SourceTechAttributes']
                        .apply(lambda x: x['MediaFormat']))
```

I only created a new column `srcMediaFormat` as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ gyoza, i am trying to use your logic on that column and trying to execute but getting error     df['SourceTechAttributes'] = (df['SourceTechAttributes']
----> 3                               .apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "")
      4                                      .replace(":", ",")
      5                                      .split(",")))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @M Hossain, I edited my code. Please try it again and let me know if it works. I basically converted float to string at 1st step.

Comment: its creates list and dictionary but when i tried to create new column df['srcMediaFormat] is giving me error, saying,  KeyError : 'MediaFormat'

Comment: It's because the pattern of each row is inconsistent. For example, a certain row does not contain `MediaFormat: xxxx`. My solution works only if the data you posted in question represents all cases.